# Circuit Design For HDMI Shut Off

Tags: transistors, triac, hdmi, scr

I am building a device that will turn on/off the HDMI to a monitor. This will allow a microcontroller to flip the monitor on and off. I tried a basic design that switches the 5V, DDC/CECGround, and HotPlugDetect wires in the HDMI cable but that didn't work 100%. I am thinking I need to switch all the wires in the HDMI cable to achieve the desired functionality.  What would be a good design to achieve this?  Think KVM switch but instead of switching between monitors its just on and off.

Here is a picture of what I have already tried.
[image: image of schematic]

Comment: There is no way of turning a monitor off by disconnecting 5V or HPD. At most it may simulate a disconnection so PC cannot see the monitor but monitor is still on and has no picture. And ground disconnection is hard, as there are several ground wires and disconnecting ground while keeping the data wires connected may result in damage. You should be more specific what you want to achieve and what circuit you had which did not work, to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: You need a high speed buffer, post a schematic of what you already tried

Comment: Please be more specific on what "100%" means.  I know many Samsung TVs will drop the picture and put up a "No Cable Connected" message if simply the +5V line is removed.  It's probably going to depend on what your target devices are and if you need/want universal compatibility.  You might at the minimum need to cut TMDS Channel 0 since it contains the sync signals.  You might also be able to get away with killing the TMDS clock channel, which is the slowest channel and is the easiest to implement most cost-effectively.  Cutting the data channels requires specialized ICs.

Comment: 100% means...Some monitors this solution worked fine for. However, when testing on other monitors the connecting of the lines as shown above did not bring the monitor out of "Looking for HDMI".  For the TMDS Channel 0 and TMDS Clock Channel, what type of electronic switch should I go with? Transistor? MOSFET? And what would the specialized IC be if I went that path?  I am assuming that a store bought KVM switch uses this specialized IC?

Comment: Your image appears to be broken.